# Korea Math Olympiad 1993

Tags: geometry, number-theory, contest-math

An integer which is the area of a right-angled triangle with integer sides is called Pythagorean. Prove that for every positive integer n > 12 there exists a Pythagorean number between n and 2n.

Comment: *Hint* : [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) are of the form $m^2-n^2$ , $2mn$ , and $m^2+n^2$. The area then can be written as $mn(m^2-n^2)=mn(m-n)(m+n)$.

Comment: @Lucian Do you think they had access to wikipedia at the Olympiad?

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri Don't be so sassy.  This is a very common formula taught in all college number theory classes.

Comment: Euclid, to whom the formula belongs, did not have any access to Wikipedia either. :-) But *we* do, and it's nice to make one's comments and answers as informative and well-documented as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we exploit the Pythagorean triple $3k,4k,5k$.

Notice because of this Pythagorean triple $6k^2$ is Pythagorean for every $k$.

**The case where $n \ge 54$:**

Choose $m\ge 3$ so that

$$6m^2 \le n < 6(m+1)^2 < 12m^2$$

This gives us the result for $n \ge 54$.

**Various smaller $n$:**

Using again our $3k,4k,5k$ triangles we can get:

For $13 \le n \le 23$ the number $24$ works (taking $k = 2$).

And for $30 \le n \le 53$ the number $54$ works (taking $k = 3$).

The only problem then comes for numbers $24 \le n \le 29$, and this is the one time we stray from our $3k,4k,5k$  method and use the triangle $5,12,13$.

For $24 \le n \le 29$ the number $30$ works.

Combining all these we have the result.

Comment: Nice. You could mention that $30$ doesn't come from a $3k,4k,5k$, but from $5,12,13$ instead, though. Also, in the fifth line you meant $m\geq 3$.

Comment: @tomasz Thank you, edited!